# Mongoose cast to ObjectID failed for value... but why

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I know what the problem is, but can't figure out why it is happening. I have a simple recipe app using express and mongoose. User passes in recipe info via form and is saved to database via mongoose methods. This part seems to work perfectly and when I console.log using test data, I see that the following data is saved:

```
{
  ingredients: [ 'peanut butter', 'jelly', 'bread' ],
  _id: 5e47d564f775ce247052d01c,
  name: 'pb jelly sammich',
  author: 'rob',
  oneLiner: 'classic pb jelly sammich',
  image: 'picofpbsammich here',
  method: 'add all the ingredients together and boom! pb jelly sammich.',
  __v: 0
}
```

(This is also what shows when I check mongo db using db.recipes.find() and also what displays when I pass in the object to my ejs show template.

However, when I access my show route via get request, I get a long error message using the above test data. Here is they key part of the error message:

```
'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "picofpbsammich here" at path "_id" for model "Recipes"',
```

I understand what the problem is, but baffled as to why it is happening. Here is my show route:

```
app.get("/recipes/:id", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.id)
    Recipe.findById(req.params.id, function (err, foundRecipe) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("show", { recipe: foundRecipe });
        }
    })
})
```

console logging the req.params.id as shown above, prints the following:

```
5e47d564f775ce247052d01c
picofpbsammich here
```

The first line is the correct ID, the second is obviously not and the cause of the problem, but I have no idea where that could be coming from :S Why would req.params.id be pulling the VALUE of a property that is named something completely different?

I'm new to mongoose so it's probably something silly I'm doing and any explanations appreciated.

Here is the model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

let recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author: String,
    oneLiner: String,
    ingredients: [String],
    image: String,
    method: String
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("Recipes", recipeSchema)
```

Comment: You `Recipes._id` is `ObjectId`, so `findById` expects ObjectId. Solution: ` Recipe.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),...`

Comment: but 5e47d564f775ce247052d01c IS ObjectID no? Where is this other random value coming from?

Comment: Post please your `Recipe` model

Comment: Model added. I've solved the problem and it is silly. It was the test data. When I use an actual image url, rather than just the dummy data (ie 'picofpbsammichhere'), it works with no issue. So I'm guessing the error is generated when the ejs template tries to access the image url. I had assumed that because I defined 'image' as String in my model, that it wouldn't matter whether I used an actual image url or not (I figured there would just be no image shown). I was confused by the error message, which suggested that the image value was being sent as an ID in req.params which made no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You posted the following code:

```
app.get("/recipes/:id", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.id)
    Recipe.findById(req.params.id, function (err, foundRecipe) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("show", { recipe: foundRecipe });
        }
    })
})
```

And you mention that in the console.log you receive:

```
5e47d564f775ce247052d01c
picofpbsammich here
```

Followed by the exception being logged:

> 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "picofpbsammich here" at path "_id"
>   for model "Recipes"',

Makes me logically assume that you are making two requests, one of which the id is not valid, being:

```
picofpbsammich here
```

Mongoose is not able to cast this value to an ObjectId, hence you get the exception, which makes sense imo.

Comment: Yea I totally get that, but based on my code, why is req.params.id return both a valid objectID and a totally random value that is passed in with a different name?

Comment: @bobby_belfast Your client is sending this value. Since this parameter looks like something you have made up, you have to find where you're making this client http call. If you're sending this call from code, perform a global search in your favorite ide on the string `picofpbsammich here` and you will find it.

Comment: It's just user inputted value from the 'new recipe' form:      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="image">Image</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="image" id="image" placeholder="image url" required>
        </div>   ...But if name is 'name', why would req.params.id be trying to interpret it as an id? :S

Comment: Check in the network tab of your browser what is sent to the api. The rest api expects an id whereas you are sending a custom string.

Comment: I've solved the problem and it is silly. It was the test data. When I use an actual image url, rather than just the dummy data (ie 'picofpbsammichhere'), it works with no issue. So I'm guessing the error is generated when the ejs template tries to access the image url. I had assumed that because I defined 'image' as String in my model, that it wouldn't matter whether I used an actual image url or not (I figured there would just be no image shown) but apparently it does matter. The error message makes no sense, I changed nothing to do with the name/id/req.params etc. Weird.

Comment: If the image url matches the endpoint, it will try to access that resource. You can fix this by foreseeing an alternate url for your images.

Comment: If the image URL is invalid, but still a string as defined in the mongoose schema, I have no idea why console.log(req.params.id) returned the objectID AND the value of the image URL. It makes no sense to me, but at least it's working I guess.

Comment: My guess is you were making two calls. Just a guess.

Comment: to the get request? Yea, I'd say so, because the console.log printed twice - first with a valid objectId, then with an invalid objectid(the 'picofpbsammich here'). What I don't know is WHY that happened, it makes no sense to me. It makes no sense why changing the value in the form from 'picofpbsammich here' to an actual image url, would change req.params. Very strange, but then I am new to mongoose so maybe theres a simple explanation.